# Reduce processing time in Erase function using Arcpy in IDLE

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, performance, erase

I am processing 18,000 feature classes (saved in a file GDB), each with ~500 records (polygon features) in ocean areas, and I am running a script to remove area overlapping with the coast, using the Erase function. The script is running successfully, but literally taking days to complete. Some files take seconds to process (I'm assuming this is due to the fact, which I've verified, that they are not overlapping with coastline) while some feature classes take over an hour to process.

I am working locally on my machine, running the script in IDLE, with ArcGIS 10.1 (all licenses) on a 32-bit Windows 7, 3.33GHz Intel DuoCore, 4GB RAM computer.

Are there any steps I can take to speed up processing time?

```
# Import modules
import arcpy
import sys
import os
from arcpy import env

arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
print arcpy.env.overwriteOutput

#Erase coastline from selected buffers.
workspace = "C:\\DIR\\points_buff\\"
arcpy.env.workspace = workspace
erase_output = workspace+"erased.gdb\\"
erasedirectorypath = "C:\\DIR\\points_buff\\selectedbuff.gdb"
fileList = []

for dirpath, dirnames, erases in arcpy.da.Walk(erasedirectorypath,
                                              datatype="FeatureClass",
                                              type="Polygon"):
    for erase in erases:
        fileList.append(os.path.join(dirpath, erase))
        filenameparts = erase.split('_')
        if int(filenameparts[1]) > int(1967):
        
            try:
        #Set variables for Erase tool
                in_features = erasedirectorypath+"\\"+erase
                coastline_feat = "C:\\DIR\\Basic_NE.gdb\\Coastline_Eastern_US"
                out_erase_feat = erase_output+erase[:-4]+"_er"
                arcpy.Erase_analysis(in_features, coastline_feat, out_erase_feat, '')
                print arcpy.GetMessages()
                print "Coastline has been erased from " + erase + " and saved to " + erase_output

            except:
                print arcpy.GetMessages()
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Although it is difficult to troubleshoot your script without seeing the spatial data, a few tricks and ideas may help your workflow.  To begin, subset your dataset and experiment with different approaches.  Incorporate a time clock into your script to get a real sense of how fast or slow operations are.  Try wrapping your commands with a `time.clock`.  For example:

```
import time
StartTime = time.clock()
arcpy.Erase_analysis(in_features, coastline_feat, out_erase_feat, '')
EndTime = time.clock()
print "Erase finished in %s hours" % ((EndTime - StartTime)/3600)
time.sleep(2.5)
```

- Try utilizing the power of [in_memory](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//002w0000005s000000) workspace.  Generally, operations performed `in_memory` are faster than those that are written to disk.  Use `in_memory` for any intermediate operations.
- Rather than using the Erase command, use the following set of
  commands to perform a similar workflow:

[Make Feature Layer (Data Management)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000006p000000)

[Select Layer by Location (Data Management)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001700000072000000)

[Delete Features (Data Management)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001700000036000000)

[Copy Features (Data Management)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001700000035000000)

- Are your polygons overly complicated?  [Dissolve (Data
  Management)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000005n000000) may help.
- Consider a raster-based approach, perhaps using a [mask](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001w0000001t000000) (if feasible).

Comment: Thanks Aaron for the tips, all are good ideas. I'll try to the time.clock option, which will be good to understand actual time of processing, but I'm not sure what to do with that information....?

Comment: Calculating time can be invaluable for comparing methods, especially if you are trying many different approaches on a small subset of data.

Comment: Great. I will also look into in_memory options...I'm wary because I only have 4GB of RAM to work with. Would this be aided by closing files (the feature classes I'm erasing from) after using the Erase function (or other functions)?

Comment: Yes, keep in mind that you can easily delete in_memory files within your script by using Delete (Data Management).

Comment: How many features are in the coastline file, and what is the typical number of vertices in a feature? How large of an area does it cover? How large of an area do your feature classes typically cover? If you have very large and complicated features in your coastline file, that might be the source of the slow down. There are a few methods to use to adjust that if it is the problem.

Comment: Aaron: I realize after some playing around that Delete Features will not work for what I'm trying to do; I want to erase the land area from the input polygon where it overlaps, but not eliminate the features that overlap. Delete Features deletes the entire feature.

Comment: Blord-Castillo: there are over 900 features in the Coastline feature class. The feature classes cover various, enormous areas, in the hundreds to thousands square kilometers. Thank you, that is a good idea to consider.

Comment: I realized after Blord-Castillo's comment that I had not projected the coastline feature class to match the projection of the features against which I am comparing it....my guess is that this would help processing time so that it does not have to project on-the-fly, however it does not seem to have sped up at all.

Comment: As @blord-castillo alluded to, it might be worth trying to simplify the coastline feature class.  Have you considered making a copy of this featureclass and dissolving all the features in it?  This would reduce the need to compare each feature in the coastline to the features in the input class.  You could see a performance gain that way.

Comment: @Get Spatial, that's a very sensible idea - I'm now comparing features to one large coastline polygon. Unfortunately it does not seem to have improved speed...

Comment: Hate to say it but you may also be running up against the simple fact of a large number of features to process, which takes time.  Based on your statement, you have 18,000 classes, with ~500 features each.  That is ~9,000,000 features total.  Even estimating .1 second per feature for processing, and this is just a WAG, you are looking at 250 hours of processing time.  The more complex the features are, the longer they take to process.  Is there any way to definitively remove some of the featureclasses from consideration?  Pre-processing seems critical here.

Comment: The combined coastline file may help, but since you have such a long processing time-frame, you may not be able to see performance gains until some significant amount of time has passed.  This is where a counter may help for processing, allowing you to gauge how many features or featureclasses you are processing per hour, for example.

Comment: I would actually go the opposite route. First dissolve the features, then break the big polygon up into several separate feature classes of one polygon each. Try running just one of these subsetted single feature coastline feature classes against one of your feature classes that took a while (and intersected). See if that gives you any improvement. I think your intersection envelopes might simply be too big, taking away any of the performance tweaks already built into overlay analyses.

Comment: Another workflow to test. Run `Minimum Bounding Geometry` on your target feature class using Group Option `ALL` and geometry type `ENVELOPE`. Perform an erase on the resulting envelope feature class using your enormous coastline. Use that output from that erase to do a `Clip` on your original target feature class. This simplifies the complex step, the erase, and substitutes it with a less costly Clip against a smaller feature.

Comment: @Get_Spatial - thanks for the suggestions, I'm researching processing counter options!

Comment: @blord-castillo, thanks - I used Editor to significantly reduce the coastal features, and then dissolve them into one polygon feature. I really like the second workflow idea, but I would need to merge all the feature classes together to make the correct Min.Bound featureclass polygon to clip out of the original coastal feature - and that won't be happening today. Cool idea to keep in mind for future reference.

Comment: @Aaron - You suggested using in_memory workspace. Would you explain what you meant? How might I perform the erase analysis in_memory? I still need to write the resulting featureclasses to a permanent file to work with later. As far as I can tell, within the loop, I'd need to save the file in_memory, execute the erase function, and then save the resulting file back permanently in a fGDB?