# Efficiently checking for feature overlaps with ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, geoprocessing, intersection, feature-class, overlapping-features

In an effort to [reduce processing time](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/59017/reduce-processing-time-in-erase-function-using-arcpy-in-idle), I am looking for ways to pre-process data within my script. I have ~18,000 featureclasses with ~500 features each (all simple circle polygons) from which I want to eliminate coastal land area (another simplified polygon) using the Erase function.

My idea for reducing overall processing time is to check for overlap between each feature class and the coastline polygon. If there *is* overlap, the script should erase the land from the features. If there is *no* overlap, the script should move on, and look at the next feature class.

### Specific questions:

1. What is the most efficient, Pythonic way to say "if there is overlap, do XX?" I cannot find documentation to do something similar to "if Overlap == True" besides the method:

   MakeFeatureLayer-->SelectFeatureByLocation-->CopyFeature-->GetRowCount--> if RowCount>0
2. Would this actually reduce processing time or am I crazy?

I'm working locally on my machine, running the script in IDLE, with ArcGIS 10.1 (with all licenses) on a 32-bit Windows 7, 3.33GHz Intel DuoCore, 4GB RAM computer.

Comment: You could use selectByLocation with Intersect, iteratively on every file, making a new file when you find intersecting geometry. Then run your script on those new files. Honestly though, you are not getting memory errors, general function failure 999999s or topology errors - I would count myself lucky and let the sucker run for a week :) Not a great answer I know...

Comment: @Tom - Thanks for the suggestion - it is a good idea, though at this point the time trade-ff isn't as good. As it is I'm already working on features that have been through several selections/pre-processing, which is why I'm looking for an in-script option while letting this functional (yay it's working!) script run while I continue to tweak it to try speeding it up. Thanks again!  Also the conversation continues on the first question if your curious about other possible solutions (see link in question above).

Comment: I liked the suggestion about the min bounding rectangle as a quick 'overlap' check. You could always implement that OR selectByLoc w/ Intersect in your script. Before you fill your fileList by walking your directory, perhaps you could throw in code that runs one of the suggested methods, outputting to a new dir, and walk that one? However I am unsure how long an erase would actually take if there is no erase to perform, so you may not see any gain. I'll keep thinking! How about multiple computers crunching away on subsets? :)

Comment: @Tom, If I could get multiple computers crunching this, I'd be a happy camper. Glad you took a look at the original question. I like your idea of throwing a subset-selection of featureclasses to a new directory and walking that one, but I'm afraid that may be too fancy for my current skillset :)

Comment: A quick note: How was your data created? You could always generalize it all first (cringes)... I generally do not like to do that, but it all depends on your end use. ie if you are using these outputs to make a map at a high scale

Comment: The features that are being checked for overlap with coastal areas are circle polygons that were buffered around points. The circles of various sizes. They are simple polygons at 1 or 2 vertices each, though I honestly wouldn't know what other criteria make them simple or complex. There's not much to do to simplify them further, that I know of.

Comment: ah yes, I have a lot of issues with circles while working w Web APIs myself. At this point, I think any pre-processing you do will need to be performed on all your layers, and given you have so many, may just slow you down.

Comment: You should consider doing these calculations with raster operations: buffering the points would be unnecessary (saving *loads* of computational time and disk I/O).

Comment: @whuber, thanks for the input! Unfortunately, raster operations would not work for later steps in my analysis.

Comment: Why not, Sharon? The result will be the same: a modified representation of the coastal land area.

Comment: The overall project involves buffering at specific distances around data points, and determining the area overlap of those (several thousand) buffered "donuts" with a polygon featureclass. I needed to remove land area so that percent area overlap is only for water-area. I'm not sure about doing this with raster - I can only imagine I'd need a very small cell size, to produce the best area calculations. I am definitely open to suggestions, though.

Comment: @SharonB The erase function is smart enough for your needs (anecdotal evidence from my tries). If you try to erase and there is no overlap, the algorithm will simply quickly return the unchanged data. I believe you need to make sure your shapefiles have a spatial index and should all be in the same coordinate system (meaning there is an index that saves bounding boxes for each feature). On the other hand, as I have no access to Erase, I wrote my own erase that uses intersect, and it seems to be quite fast too (I run it with about 600,000 polygons, cutting off intersections).

Comment: @MichalisAvraam - thanks for your comments. Everything is in the same coordinate system/projection, if that's what you meant by "spatial index." Erase has been working well, if slowly. The biggest improvement I can see, (from anecdotal observation from wrapping the script in time functions) - has been from working in in_memory; features that do not overlap are scanned in usually under 30 seconds. However, those that do overlap still take anywhere from a few minutes to 1.5 hrs to run.

Comment: @SharonB I was referring to spatial indices as described here: http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001700000060000000 (note that file geodatabases may already have them, you can check through the describe object).

Comment: @SharonB Is the coast polygon a single feature with lots and lots of vertices?

Comment: @Matthew - Yes, it is. Over 33,000 vertices. You may be getting at the idea of simplifying the coast polygon before the analysis. If i had the opportunity to do this project over, I definitely would.

Answer (score 3):

Coastline data is a case where bounding box spatial indexing can be of limited benefit.  Consider the example below.

[image]

Both polygons A and B are within the bounding box of the land polygon.  The software may need to work through each of the thousands of vertices to identify if the polygons actually overlap.  This work could be reduced by simplifying the land polygon and reducing the vertex count.

Alternatively you can divide the land polygon into a grid.  This will make the spatial indexing much more useful and reduce the number of vertices to process.  Based on the grid shown below, only the tiles in red would be identified as intersecting using bounding box spatial indexing.  Polygon B would show as not intersecting without needing to process the land vertices at all.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Don't know if this is still an open question, but an idea that occurred to me was that if you had the points/centroids from which your circle polygons were generated, you might be able to more quickly assess their euclidean distance from the coast, select those below a threshold, and then relate these points to the polygon feature class and use that for a single erase operation.